# Google FCM Invalid_argument when sending message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to figure out how to do push notifications to Android using Firebase and got it working using the legacy HTTP (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) but the documentation suggests using the newer endpoint (https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send).  I can't seem to get it working because I keep getting this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

This occurs using the sample at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-916177026973/messages:send HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 81403929-77ba-4568-8681-a854527ccb22
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <token redacted>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/6.4.1
Accept: */*
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 319
Connection: close

{
  "message":{
    "token" : <token redacted>,
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message",
      }
   }
}
```

I also tried with the last comma removed to make it compliant with JSON and still no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain that you are using the correct project Id? It looks like this part "/project-916177026973/" contains your Sender Id. When you open the Firebase console your project Id will be a part of the URL.

Comment: @Barns hallelujah!  Thanks - make it a solution and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP pointed out Firebase now suggest to the FCM v1 endpoint if you want to send messages via HTTP.

> To send messages via HTTP, send an HTTP POST request to the FCM v1
>   endpoint and specify the send method. The endpoint URL must contain
>   the project ID of the Firebase project for your app, available in the
>   General project settings tab of the Firebase console.

It will look something like this:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/your_project_id_here/messages:send HTTP/
```

The section of the URL `your_project_id_here`  is **your** project id. You will need to find the project specific `project Id` which is located in the `Settings` section of the Firebase console for your project under the tab `General`.

Look for `Project ID`. If you have any doubts about your correct `Project ID` it is also a part if the URL in the website address to your project. It looks like:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/your_project_id_here/settings/general/android:your_project_name
```

Comment: Uses topic help me to see the real problem. In my case I changed the firebase account and create a new serviceAccountKey.json. But.. I still used the same token on app, created by oldest account.